# Bootstrap progress bar does not start from 0%

Tags: bootstrap-5

Bootstrap progress bar does not start from 0% like it's indented but I only copy pasted the code from the documentations. See the image linked below

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-1">
          Skill:
     </div>
     <div class="col-11 align-self-center progress">
               <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
               70%
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

progress bar  looks like this
[progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mYHC.png)

The progress is intended to be 70% full but to the left of the bar the blue area doesn't fill all the way from 0% to 70%, instead there is a gap at the first few % before the bar begins to appear as blue.

Comment: Can't repro this https://codeply.com/p/XCpVAZCFK0 works fine when you set the appropriate values to 0

Comment: @Zim i edited it to show more of the code, perhaps it can help

Comment: You've set `aria-valuenow="70"` which logically makes the progress bar start at 70%...

Comment: @akseli i want it to be at 70%

Comment: @wiSHrew then I really don't understand your question...

Comment: @akseli the progress bar does not start from 0% instead there's a bit of space at the start. look at the linked image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `col-*` classes on the progress bar itself. Nest the progress bar within the column.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      Skill:
    </div>
    <div class="col-11 align-self-center">
      <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-label="Basic example" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```